# TypeScript doesn't care about `instanceof` in function overload

Tags: typescript

Perfectly good for runtime code is with error in TypeScript (v4.5.5):

```
class A {}
class B {}

function testFn(elem: A): 'true';
function testFn(elem: B): false;
function testFn(elem: A | B) {
  if (elem instanceof A) return 'true';

  return false;
}

const val1: 'true' = testFn(new A()); // Okay
const val2: false = testFn(new B()); // Error. val2 is considered to be 'true'
```

This is prone to some really nasty bugs in code.

Comment: `A` and `B` are structurally equivalent. See [What is structural typing?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and [Why do these empty classes behave strangely?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) If you have any properties in them, especially methods, chances are they are going to be different. See [When and why are classes nominal?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal) Or are you really after nominal typing with empty classes?

Comment: ① You mean *overload*, not *override*. Those terms look similar but are distinct. ② Overloads don't care about much of *anything* in the function. You could change `(elem instanceof A)` to `(Math.random()<0.5)` and it will behave the same. `instanceof` is a red herring here. ③ The issue is as @VLAZ says, that `A` and `B` are structurally identical and empty. You could even call `testFn(123)` or `testFn("oopsiedaisy")` given your definitions. This might be surprising but is a well-documented feature of TS. ⊛ Does this fully address the question or is something missing?